# What is the usage of 先 vs. 元?

Tags: word-choice, usage, kanji

I think that the both of them mean before, but I have seen that they are sometimes use in parent-child metaphors, but I always get confused with these. 
Some examples of ○○先、○○元 words would be appreciated.

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: Some examples that get you confused would help us help you…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anything, they're more like antonyms. 先　denotes 'destination', while 元 denotes 'source', or 'beginning', or 'essence'.

先:

- 宛先, 届け先: delivery address
- 行き先: destination (of a trip)

元:

- 根元: by the root (e.g. of a tree)
- 元値: "beginning price" (original price paid by retailer).
- 元素： (chemical) element.